# How can I get key values belonging to multiple groups in my source data?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I get the `RM_ID` values the belonging to multiple groups in my source data?

I have two columns in my table: `RM_ID` and `Group`, with and data like this:

| RM_ID | GROUP |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | DEF |
| 100 | DEF |
| 200 | ABC |
| 200 | ABC |
| 200 | DEF |
| 300 | XYZ |
| 300 | XYZ |
| 300 | ABC |
| 400 | PQR |
| 400 | PQR |

- I want to identify all the `RM_ID` who belong to more than one group, and also retrieve the groups' names'.
- How can I achieve that in Oracle?

  - Will the `LEAD`/`LAG` function help here?

Desired Result:

| RM_ID | GROUP |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | ABC |
| 200 | DEF |
| 300 | XYZ |
| 300 | ABC |

Comment: Can you add the desired result as a table as well?

Comment: Added the desired output

Comment: What is the `PRIMARY KEY` of your table? Is every pair of `RM_ID` and `GROUP` values guaranteed to be unique in the table - or not? (If so, then you have a duplicate in your source data (`100`, `'DEF'`)).

Comment: Yes there are duplicates in my sample data based on RM_ID and GROUP, but there are other columns as well which I have not displayed here.

Comment: Should the duplicates be there or not? How should duplicates be counted? (Is `RM_ID 100` in group `DEF` _twice_ or just once?)

Comment: Duplicates can be counted once. I just need to identify the RM_ID (along with Group) which belong to multiple group,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a couple of steps. I'll use some CTE's to make it clearer.

First get the distinct pairs of values, Then use a window function to count the number of groups per RM_ID, and then select the records with more than 1 group.

```
WITH DISTINCT_PAIRS AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    RM_ID, 
    GROUP_
  FROM YOUR_TABLE), 

GROUP_COUNTER AS (
  SELECT 
    RM_ID, 
    GROUP_, 
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY RM_ID) AS NO_OF_UNIQUE_GROUPS
  FROM DISTINCT_PAIRS
)

SELECT 
  RM_ID, 
  GROUP_
FROM GROUP_COUNTER 
WHERE NO_OF_UNIQUE_GROUPS > 1
```

Alternatively you can do it like this, a little less verbose:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  RM_ID, 
  GROUP_
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE RM_ID IN (
  SELECT 
    RM_ID
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  GROUP BY RM_ID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT GROUP_) > 1
)
```

Comment: You might want to escape the `GROUP` keyword being used as a column name to keep SQL tooling happy.

Comment: Way more complicated than it should be.

Comment: David דודו Markovitz, agreed. Included a shorter example. Just wanted to show the thought process.

Comment: Code should not be published if not tested first.